# What is the value of the following integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

As disscussed in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Zero-variance_limit) , we have:

[image]

now suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are normal random variables with zero-variance limit and zero mean, what is the value of the following integral?

$$f(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty p_X(x-z)p_Y(y-z)dz$$

$x$ and $y$ are real numbers.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(z)\delta(z-x)dz=f(x)
$$
Therefore if $x\neq y$:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p_X(x-z)p_Y(y-z)dz=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p_X(x-z)p_Y(y-x)dz=0.
$$
However if $x=y$, then we have:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p_X(x-z)p_Y(x-z)dz=
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p_X(x-z)p_Y(0)dz=\delta(0)
$$
which is arbitrarily large at zero.

---

The above lines should be looked upon with care. firstly the first integration is not a Riemman integral and secondly $f$ should be continuous so writing the result of last integral as $\delta(0)$ is just heuristic.

Comment: Isn't this a product of distributions? I have not seen a consistent formulation handling products of distributions. Why do we know this is sensible?

Comment: @Arash so the answer would be infinite?

Comment: Honestly I am reluctant to put infinity there because $\delta$, properly speaking is not a function and even more one cannot say that its value at zero is infinity.